# How to have a resizeable textarea with other non-resizable boxes?

Tags: html, css, textarea

I have been trying for a while to get my code to work.  I am trying to have a textarea take up the entire page except for a few navigation bars that do not resize.  I had it working fine, but the scroll bars were being partially blocked off, so I have to have the textarea on taking up the open space instead of using padding to have it avoid the navigation bars.

Here is my HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="topbar"></div>
<div id="tabbar"></div>
<div id="sidebar"></div>
<textarea wrap="off" id="maintext" autofocus="autofocus"> </textarea>
</body>
```

and here is my CSS:

```
#topbar{
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
right: -1px;
left: -1px;
border: 1px solid black;
height: 35px;
background: black;
z-index: 1;
}
#tabbar{
position: fixed;
right: -1px;
left: -1px;
height: 20px;
background: grey;
margin: 29px auto;
border: 1px solid grey;
z-index: 2;
}
#sidebar{
position: fixed;
height: 100%;
left: 0px;
width: 15px;
margin: 51px auto;
border: 1px solid lightgrey;
background: lightgrey;
z-index: 3;
}
#maintext{
position: fixed;
right: 0px;
bottom: 50px;
left: 0px;
top: 58px;
margin-left: 20px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border: none;
outline: none;
resize: none;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### IE8+ (Preferred)

Here is a rough example which shows the `textarea` completely (i.e. nothing is clipped): http://jsfiddle.net/UvJAM/1/

It can be modified to do exactly what you want, but has the caveat of using `box-sizing`, which isn't supported in IE7 and below.

I also added a wrapper around the `textarea` so that top/bottom offset can be managed with padding.

```
<div id="textwrapper">
    <textarea wrap="off" id="maintext" autofocus="autofocus"></textarea>
</div>
```

### IE7

http://jsfiddle.net/UvJAM/4/

This model is less flexible because it limits the styling of the `textarea`, i.e. any padding or border will break it. However, it does support IE7 (at least in emulation mode). Also works in IE9 and Chrome.

The important part is the use of 4-part position statements to achieve 100% height and width.

```
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

`DIV`s are much more flexible than `TextArea`s when it comes to CSS styling. Perhaps you could consider using a `DIV` with the `contentEditable` attribute (see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Content_Editable). It's an HTML5 standard but surprisingly well supported in much older browsers (IE6, FF3.5) but seldom used.

If you do want to continue using a `textarea`, though, the following modifications to your `#maintext` CSS, i think, achieves what you want. You set the width and height to 100% which actually makes the text area as wide and tall as the body. So when you position it, it actually overflows the page.

```
#maintext{
position: fixed;
right: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
left: 20px;
top: 58px;
border: none;
outline: none;
resize: none;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-left: 0px;
}
```

More detail about `contenteditable` here: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#contenteditable